# Problem with filtering data with Jquery and flask (leaflet app)

Tags: python, jquery, flask, leaflet

I try to filter a geojson layer on leaflet using checkboxes. My layer is correctly displayed, but when I click on the boxes, nothing happens. I have a correct url in the flask server which shows me that the request is taken into account. I use data back from Postgresql. How can I display this filtered information on my map? I think it's from my python code but I can't figure how to do it.

**JS code :**

```
    function refreshroutesfermees(whr) {   
        if (whr) {
            var objData = {tbl:'routes_fermees_adn', flds:"id, cpx_numero, cpx_gestio, fermeture, dep", where:whr};
        } else {
            var objData = {tbl:'routes_fermees_adn', flds:"id, cpx_numero, cpx_gestio, fermeture, dep"};
        }
        $.ajax({
        url: '/routes_fermees', ///retrieve my data from app.py
        data: objData,
        type: 'POST',          
        success: function (response) {
             if (response=="ERROR"){
                alert (response);
            } else { 
            arProjectIDs=[];
            if (lyrroutesfermees) {
                ctlLayers.removeLayer(lyrroutesfermees);
                lyrroutesfermees.remove();
            }
            lyrroutesfermees = L.geoJSON(response, 
            {style:styleroutesfermees, onEachFeature:processroutesfermees});
            ctlLayers.addOverlay(lyrroutesfermees, "routes fermées");
            arProjectIDs.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
            }
    },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("ERROR: " + error);
        }
    });
    }
```

**HTML checkboxes :**

```
   

    $("#btnFilterroutesfermees").click(function(){
                  var arTypes=[];
                  var cntChecks=0;
                    $("input[name=fltferme]").each(function(){
                        if (this.checked) {
                            if(this.value=='ferm 38'){
                                arTypes.push("'38'");
                                cntChecks++;
                            }
                            if(this.value=='ferm 73'){
                                arTypes.push("'73'");
                                cntChecks++;
                            }
                            if(this.value=='ferm 74'){
                                arTypes.push("'74'");
                                cntChecks++;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                  //  alert(cntChecks);
                    if (cntChecks==0) {
                        refreshroutesfermees("1=2");
                    } else if (cntChecks==3){ ////le nombre de checkbox
                        refreshroutesfermees();
                    } else {
                    //    alert("type IN ("+arTypes.toString()+")");
                    refreshroutesfermees("dep IN ("+arTypes.toString()+")");
                    }
                });
```

**Part of the app.py**

```
    @app.route('/routes_fermees', methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def routes_fermees():
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("""
                select json_build_object(
                    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
                    'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(routes_fermees_adn.*)::json)
                ) as geojson
                from routes_fermees_adn
                """)
            return cur.fetchone()[0]
```

**The link created from flask**

```
  GET /routes_fermees?tbl=routes_fermees_adn&flds=id%2C%20cpx_numero%2C%20cpx_gestio%2C%20fermeture%2C%20dep
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only add the new layer to L.LayerControl, but not the map itself. From Leaflet's documentation:

> [addOverlay](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-addoverlay): Adds an overlay (checkbox entry) with the given name to the control.

Try adding `.addTo(map)` after the L.geoJSON call, where `map` is your Leaflet map instance. Like this:

```js
    lyrroutesfermees = L.geoJSON(response, {
        style: styleroutesfermees,
        onEachFeature: processroutesfermees
     }).addTo(map); // <- Adds the geoJSON features to the map.
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Thank you! I did it on purpose so that it wouldn't load on display (lots of layers) but trying again still doesn't work... Maybe I should send this request back to the server and send a new filtered layer back to the map, using python (server side)?

Comment: Can you confirm that the view (`routes_fermees()`) returns the correct data? From what I see, the view does not take any of the given parameters from the ajax call into account - as the query is static. In general: If you can, try to provide a minimal working example that reproduces the problem. This helps anyone to debug the problem and increases the chances of a good answer drastically :-)